# Linking failed when use indirectly the GNU linker

Tags: hyperlink, gnu, g++

The following line generate the executable :

```
arm-none-eabi-ld  -L/home/th/opt/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -L/home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/  -T /home/th/autoreverse/game/game.ld   main.cpp.obj init.cpp.obj syscalls.cpp.obj queue.cpp.obj echange.cpp.obj echangeur.cpp.obj startup.s.obj  -lstdc++ -lc -lgcc -o game.elf
```

...but replacing ld call by g++ call, do not do the job :

```
arm-none-eabi-g++  -L/home/th/opt/arm-none-eabi/lib/ -L/home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/  -T /home/th/autoreverse/game/game.ld   main.cpp.obj init.cpp.obj syscalls.cpp.obj queue.cpp.obj echange.cpp.obj echangeur.cpp.obj startup.s.obj  -lstdc++ -lc -lgcc -o game.elf
/home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: main.cpp.obj: in function `std::__ioinit':
/home/th/autoreverse/game/main.cpp:43: multiple definition of `__dso_handle'; /home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o: in function `_start':
/home/th/tools/newlib-cygwin-build/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm/semihv2m/../../../../../newlib-cygwin/libgloss/arm/crt0.S:430: undefined reference to `__bss_start__'
/home/th/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /home/th/tools/newlib-cygwin-build/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm/semihv2m/../../../../../newlib-cygwin/libgloss/arm/crt0.S:430: undefined reference to `__bss_end__'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Calling g++ with arguments "-v" print the complete g++ command. That's when I saw that g++ include some C runtime files : crtbegin, crti and crt0.

One of thoses files requests for **bss_start**' and **bss_end**'.

I don't need thoses files ! Remove theses with "-nostdlib" argument.